# Unable to install packages or rload repository

Tags: 18.04, package-management, repository, reinstall

I'm having issues with updating or installing all packages in ubuntu 18.04.

I was trying to load openvpn so followed some instructions to edit my /etc/apt/source.list and now nothing is working. I have regenerated the source list using the ubuntu sources generator https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php but it doesn't seem to help.
I have also tried recreating the list using sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list but the issue isn't resolved

When I run sudo apt-get update I get the time out errors (see comment)

I have tried to change settings in the software & updates. However, when I try to reload the repositories I get the error saying download failed and to check internet connection. I have tried multiple servers including the main server and the same issues occurs.

When I try to install synaptic (and all other packages) I get these error messages
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate

After trying everything I could, I opted to uninstall then reinstall 18.04. After reinstalling there are no improvements and I'm receiving the same errors.

If anyone has any ideas for a solution it would be much appreciated.

Comment: apt-get update errors are as follows

Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.174), con

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Similar issue but I've tried all of the solutions posted to that question and it hasn't resolved the issue

Comment: It seems that you have problems with internet connection. You can try to use other connection such as 3G/4G Wi-Fi hotspot.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use IPv6 to connect. Is that intentional?